# how to remove the name in email id

Tags: php, regex, email

I have some email formats like

```
 iba@test.co - Admin,iwi@test.co - Kika,mla@test.co - Mka,
```

I need to send the email in php for multiple id's now due to above name its sees to error

***Expected output***

```
 iba@test.co,iwi@test.co,mla@test.co,
```

I need to remove the name after the all mail id how can i do that i have tried `str_replace` but thats not gives me a solution.

How can i use `preg_match` in this case ?

Comment: Replace [`\s*-.*?,`](https://regex101.com/r/wR5dE7/2) by `,`. OR match [`(\w+@\S+\.\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/wR5dE7/3)

Comment: why is the input in that format to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reg Exp**

```
$list = 'iba@test.co - Admin,iwi@test.co - Kika,mla@test.co - Mka,';
$str = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote('-') .'.*?'.preg_quote(',') . '/', ',', $list);
```

**Rtrim** To remove the end comma

```
$str = rtrim($str, ',');
```

Comment: I'm getting output something like this `iba@test.co ,iwi@test.co ,mla@test.co ,` now how can i remove the spaces after `,` ?

Comment: To remove spacing's   $str = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote(' - ') .'.*?'.preg_quote(',') . '/', ',', $list);